# how does Swing instanciate the UI controls?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

Here's my GUI class, designed with IntelliJ editor:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 public class MainForm {
        private JPanel panel;
        private JButton button1;

        public MainForm() {
            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World!");
                }
            });

            }       
    }
```

When I instanciate an instance, it does display my frame as expected :

```
 MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
```

I do not understand why it works. From my point of view, button variable is declared but never instanced.
So it should be null when the constructor line tries to execute this:

```
 button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()...
```

I would be expecting a null exception but somehow, it looks that a button is actually istanced.

Can anyone explain me what actually happens?

Comment: The behavior you see here is a feature of IntelliJ IDEA, not of Swing itself.

Comment: some IoC embedded stuff I suppose?

Comment: See linked question.